# Remaster Ubuntu

Tags: remastersys

I want to remaster ubuntu Lucid in maverick, is it possible? Is there a conflict?

For example when I do the chroot, or to update the repository in the new ubuntu environment, (from the "iso" which I extract), or something else..

and is it possible to remaster Ubuntu 32bit from 64bit machine?

Answer (score 2):

There is a comprehensive document on remastering the live CD [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization).  While it is not trivial to create an Ubuntu amd64 CD on an i386 system, creating an i386 CD on an amd64 system should work without issue.

Comment: thank you. but what about remastering Lucid in the maverick? (With the same architecture)

Answer (score 0):

When you try to chroot from a 32-bit to a 64-bit enviroment you get an error, it won't chroot. I haven't tried the other way round, but have read it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [method described on the wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization), it should not matter what release you are using to do the modification. You will have problems trying to remaster a 64-bit system on a 32-bit system, but not the other way around.

Comment: oh, thank you for your link for customization ubuntu. it is really helpful for me. but I idly remastered Ubuntu Lucid 32bit on my Lucid 64bit ubuntu machine with Ubuntu customization kit. and it can run perfectly, could be installed as well. Is the live cd that I made it absolutely perfect or there any that I miss?

Comment: You're right about that. I've corrected my answer.