# make my ubuntu a live disk from my hard disk

Tags: 11.10, live-cd

is there any way to create a ubuntu live disk that includes all apps in my pc? i installed a lot of apps & gnome 3.2 on my ubuntu 11.10 & i want to share them with my friends on a disk that is live & able to install my distro on their PCs. do you have any idea?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/6766/remaster-ubuntu

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)

Answer (score 1):

None of the previous answers mention `bootcd`, that seems to correspond exactly to your question. Nevertheless, I never tried it.

This is the package description:

> ```
>  Build an image of your running Debian System with the command bootcdwrite.
>  You can also build a bootcd ISO image via NFS on a remote System.
>  When you run your system from CD you do not need any disks. All
>  changes will be done in ram. To reuse this changes at next boot time
>  you can save them on FLOPPY with the command bootcdflopcp. If booting
>  from your CD-drive is not supported, booting from FLOPPY is possible.
>  It is possible to install a new system from the running CD with the
>  command bootcd2disk. Bootcd2disk can also find a target disk, format
>  it and make it bootable automatically. Bootcd also supports lilo,
>  grub, initrd, udev, lvm, transparent-compression ISO 9660 fs and
>  syslinux/isolinux. The included FAQ describes how bootcd can do
>  online or offline backups of other Linux distributions, resulting
>  in restore-bootcds. The bootcdbackupwizard helps to create online
>  backups.
> ```